# My page menu does not show the view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement page menu from https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu . I am using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier instead of NibName for creating my UIViewControllers. But none of my Controllers are adding to the menu page. Here is my code:

```
    var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    let vc1 = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PeopleSearchTableViewController")
    let vc2 = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HashtagsSearchTableViewController")

    vc1.title = "People"
    vc2.title = "Hashtags"

    controllerArray.append(vc1)
    controllerArray.append(vc2)

    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor (UIColor.whiteColor()),
        .SelectionIndicatorColor (UIColor (netHex: 0x3CBB5B, alpha: 100)),
        .SelectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor (netHex: 0x3CBB5B, alpha: 100)),
    ]

    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
```

But it doesn't show neither hashtags page nor people page, and I can't switch from people to hostages. Anybody can help?

Thanks!

Comment: In the storyboard, have you checked the box in the identity inspector of the UIViewControllers that says - Use Storyboard ID?

Comment: Yes I have checked the box, but it doesn't work.

Comment: try this- 
let vc1:UITableViewController = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PeopleSearchTableViewController") as PeopleSearchTableViewController

Comment: Thanks,I tried this but still not working.Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue - you need to add `self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)` above `self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)`